# Partial Derivative which when evaluated gives $0/0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My function is $f(x,y)=xy\frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ EDIT defined $f(0,0)=0$ (How does that impact the evaluation of partial derivatives?)

I need to evaluate the function at $f_{xy}(0,0)$ and similarly for $f_{yx}(0,0)$ My problem is that upon evaluating the function at (0,0), I get cases of $0/0$ How can I get around it? Should I try rearranging terms with algebra?

Comment: Your function is not defined at (0,0). You might try evaluating what happens in the limit as you approach the origin along any line.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the function is given as defined at $f(0,0)=0$ But I didn't think this had relevance for the partial derivatives.

Comment: ...evaluate teh function **at** $f_{xy}(0,0)$, I think is meaningless. Maybe you want to verify if $f(x,y)$ has $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ at the origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the definition of derivative to find $f'_x$ and $f'_y$ at $(0,0)$; for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ you just use differentiate the expression for $f$ as usual. Then you have formulas $f'_x(x,y)$ equal to something at $(0,0)$ and something else elsewhere, and similarly for $f'_y(x,y)$. Then you *again* use the definition of derivative on those functions to get $f''_{xy}$ and $f''_{yx}$ at $(0,0)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I have done the differentiation...my point is that at (0,0), I get the form of 0/0.

Comment: The expressions you get by differentiating $xy(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)$ only say what the derivatives are for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$; it's completely meaningless to try to substitute $x=y=0$ into those formulas, if that's what you're doing when you're getting 0/0. To find $f'_x(0,0)$, you must do an entirely different computation, namely calculate $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}(f(h,0)-f(0,0))$.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Let $y=ax$ and take the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$.

**Edit:** If the result of taking the above limit is not a constant but a function of $a$, the limit does not exist. You can, however, find the value of $f_{xy}(0,0)$ or $f_{yx}(0,0)$ from a particular direction by picking $a$ such that $y=ax$ defines the line along which you want to approch $(0,0)$.